# How to check the html version any web application is using?

Tags: html

how  can i check what html version my web application is using? I have complete code base but i am not sure where to check the html version?  In jsp i do not see see anything related to html version.

**EDIT:-** On google . most of the stuff says , do the page source , the very first line tells the html version. When i do the same isee

```
 <!doctype html>
```

Now i am not sure, what version of html ishould make out from above line?

Comment: first line should have a `<!DOCTYPE...>` declaration.

Comment: It just says <!doctype html>. i am not sure what version of html i should make out from this line?

Comment: If it would have been html 4 or 3, what i should  have expected instead of <!DOCTYPE html>?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Check the [DOCTYPE](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) declaration in the html file.

HTML5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

HTML 4.01 Strict

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Comment: Can i also check for some html libraries in my code to confirm html 5 apart from doctype?

Comment: You can run the file thru a validator to verify its valid html code.  For example I use [W3 Markup Service](http://validator.w3.org). You can also upload the file.

Comment: @BlackFrog i see some projects not using HTML5 but still using `<!DOCTYPE html>` ? Is `<!DOCTYPE html>` not strict for only hrml5 or lower html version can also use this tag ?

Comment: I don't have a `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration in my jsp, so how to know which version of html is embedded in my jsp page?

Comment: I tried to validate my jsp in the site you mentioned (W3 Markup Service) but it says   `Sorry, this type of URL scheme (undefined) is not supported by this service. Please check that you entered the URL correctly.

URLs should be in the form: https://validator.w3.org/`

Comment: What is the url?

Comment: You cannot validate the content of your jsp file. You have to validate what your web server renders from the jsp content. The resulting html document. I